# Возможно ли прислать на клиент скрытое от человека числовое значение?

Tags: javascript, криптография

Необходимо прислать на клиент числовое значение (float), которое сможет распознать только скрипт JS, а человеку потребуется хотя бы час для перебора в ручную или программными средствами. Предполагаю, что если это и возможно сделать, то должно быть реализовано с помощью криптографии, возможно в комбинации с "замудренными" математическими операциями. Возможно ли такое реализовать, и как?

Comment: Невозможно, всё, что доступно скрипту, доступно человеку сразу же)

Comment: Пока у человека есть возможность заглянуть в память программы - он просто прочитает из памяти готовый результат после всех этих ваших математических операций.

Answer (score 2):

Если есть какие-то данные, к которым пользователь не должен иметь полного доступа, то эти данные лучше не отправлять. В вашем случае я бы посоветовал пересмотреть подход таким образом, что бы исключить обмен sensitive data, но если очень хочется - то я мог бы посоветовать два варианта: SSR (но вам он, вероятно, не подойдёт) и кодирование-декодирование ответа. Если вы прибегнете к кодированию-декодированию - то необходимо убедиться в том, что sensitive data как минимум:

1. Не кэшируется
2. Получается через POST (SSL)
3. Предполагаемое время декодирования данных превышает их срок жизни

В [этом вопросе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39568719/rest-api-get-with-sensitive-data) можно найти больше информации по теме.